# Next.js server side logging in getServerSideProps or api?

Tags: next.js, papertrail-app

What is best practice for logging on the server side in Next.js?

I have code that syncs two databases and I need to see the log. I was thinking about using an external logging service like Papertrail, but I can't find any examples.

What are you using?

Comment: You may want to check official examples on Github, eg with Sentry: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sentry

Comment: Eg. with a custom package (on NPM): https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-logs